# Knockout js: How to do a computed value based on a submodel?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, knockout.js

This is my jsfiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/v42uw/6/

```
var Goal = function (goal) {


    var self = this;

    this.GoalId = ko.observable(goal ? goal.GoalId : "0");
    this.GoalTitle = ko.observable(goal ? goal.GoalTitle : "").extend({ required: " " });
    this.Weightage = ko.observable(goal ? goal.Weightage : "").extend({ required: " " });



    this.lstSubGoals = ko.observableArray(goal ? ko.utils.arrayMap(goal.lstSubGoals, function (goal) { return new Goal(goal) }) : []);

    this.GoalReview = ko.observable(goal ? (goal.GoalReview ? new GoalReview(goal.GoalReview, goal) : null) : null);

};
```

I have a viewmodel which has sub models and it is recursive. The model has a Score property. The requirement is the Score property can be changed only at the last child model. Once it is changed, the changes have to be applied to the parent model. Please help me out how to do it in knockoutjs?

Answer (score 2):

Your question is unclear, but as long as you use observables and observable arrays your computed can resolve any dependencies to underlying observables.

http://jsfiddle.net/KMapD/

```
this.total = ko.computed(function() {
    var total = 0;
    ko.utils.arrayForEach(this.items(), function(item) {
       total += parseFloat(item.sub());
    });
    return total;
}, this);
```

Just be aware of ordo n ^2 problems and circular dep

**Update:**
recursive example:

http://jsfiddle.net/KMapD/2/

Comment: Thanks for the help. I have updated my fiddle. Please check this jsfiddle.net/v42uw/6 . Score has to be given only for the last sub goal. Based on this, the subsequent parent goals Score has to be calculated. Please help me how to go about it.

Comment: Recursive model design makes no difference, just itterate over it recursivly from the computed

Comment: I think you should be able to solve that, but I'm a nice guy :D Updated example

Comment: Test to click the add button on the second example, trust me, its recursive

Comment: Have a computed on each level then, let the parent computed execute each of it's child computed. Everhing is easy with KO :)